# Can someone rectify the code and explain why gets() is not reading the value properly?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, gets

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Emp{
    int empno;
    char name[100];
    char designation[100];
    float basic;
} employee;

int main(){
    
    cout<<"ID: ";
    cin>>employee.empno;
    
    cout<<"Name: ";
    gets(employee.name);
    
    cout<<"Designation: ";
    gets(employee.designation);
    
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Details: "<<endl;
    cout<<employee.empno<<endl;
    cout<<employee.name<<endl;
    cout<<employee.designation<<endl;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkj8i.png

When I run the code, the cursor skips 'gets(employee.name)' and goes to 'gets(employee.designation)'. Can anyone clarify the reason for this behavior and suggest a method to correct it?

Comment: [Never use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)!!

Comment: The `cin>>employee.empno;` leaves a newline character that gets consumed by the first `gets()` call.

Comment: Thanks @FredLarson. What do you suggest an alternative for gets()? What are your thoughts on getline()?

Comment: `std::getline()` is good, but note that it will retain the `'\n'` in the string it reads in. You'll probably want to trim that off. And I do suggest that you use `std::string`, not C-style strings.